# Change GET parameter in URL in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I make a searchable ListView. I pass parameters in request.GET dictionnary.
The problem is when I'm on page 21, if I change parameters of the query, I have a new queryset which may have less than 21 pages. The default behavior is too raise a 404. I override the method *paginate_queryset* to check if it's the case and if so I set the page_number to 1.
The problem is that when I'm on my browser

```
go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/utilisateur/liste?page=21&Utilisateur-appareil=#
```

it works as expected but if I change Utilisateur-appareil value in the form and I submit. I'm on the page :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/utilisateur/liste?page=21&Utilisateur-appareil=13#
```

I'm now on the page 1 of my view because there is not 21 pages create by the paginator. But the Uri stay with the parameter **page=21**
I'd like to override this behavior. I've already check if I modify the request.GET dictionnary (bad thing) that doesn't change the URI response.

Comment: You can redirect your user to the url you want, e.g. `return HttpResponseRedirect('/utilisateur/liste?page=1&Utilisateur-appareil=13#')`

Comment: @Alasdair I'm not sure but if I redirect the user to this URL I'll have to calculate and request the database one more time for build the queryset and when I realize that my ListView has not 21 page I've already do the most of the job.
So this solution works but it is not efficient.

Comment: It isn't possible for the response to change the browser's url unless you redirect the user. Yes, this will cause another request, but in practice the extra request and database queries might not be a problem. Another option would be to use javascript to change the url with the [`pushState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) API.